# como posso verificar o tamanho de texto de um input React-Native?

Tags: input, react-native, text

ola, eu preciso pegar o texto de um input em react-native e verificar se este texto digitado tem menos q 11 caracteres, como eu poderia fazer essa verificacao? sou novo com react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Onde esta armazenado o texto? No estado de um componente? Se for o caso, basta checar `this.state.seuTexto.length`.

(2) Quando precisa checar? Na maneira que digita ou quando clicar um botao?

(2.1) Pro primeiro, pode usar `onChangeText` em um TextInput da seguinte maneira:

```
onChangeText={text => {
  if (text.length < 11) {
    // tem menos de onze
  }
  // atualiza o estado
  this.setState({ seuTexto: text });
}}
```

(2.2) Pra checar depois de clicar um botao, basta checar no onPress

```
onPress={() => {
  if (this.state.seuTexto.length < 11) {
    // menos de 11
  }
}}
```

*Nota: (aconselho a extrair as funções pra fora do render)*

Comment: obrigado, embora eu ja tenha conseguido. Era exatamente isso msm.